# Image slide across screen - CSS3

Tags: html, animation, css

Does anyone know where I can find an example of an image sliding in from the left of the screen stopping in the middle for a few seconds the continues across the page.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [**keyframe animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes), like this:

## [*example*](http://dabblet.com/gist/3834617)

**HTML**:

```
<img src='image.jpg'>
```

**CSS**:

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    margin: 7em -244px;
    animation: slide 4s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% { left: -150%; }
    35% { left: 50%; }
    65% { left: 50%; }
    100% { left: 150%; }
}
```

Comment: I am new to web development. This isn't work for me. I have linked to the css file in the header of the HTML file; I have the DOCTYPE specified as well as the HTML, header, and body tags. My css file contains exactly what's in your block above. What more do I need to do?